# How does IFS replace char?

Tags: bash

I thought that IFS is used to split strings into words in bash. How does this join function work? [(source)](https://zaiste.net/posts/how-to-join-elements-of-array-bash/):

```
function join { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }
```

Example:

```
$ arr=( 1 a 2 b c d e 3 )
$ join , "${arr[@]}"
1,a,2,b,c,d,e,3
```

This seems to replace space with the first parameter passed to join.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assuming that `$*` always joins with spaces. It actually joins on the first character of `IFS`.

Here's `man bash` which describes `$*` under "Special Parameters":

> [...] When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.
> That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c...", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable.  If IFS is  unset,  the  parameters  are
> separated by spaces.  If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.